# ReactJS: destructured variables of mapped array of objects is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

i am trying to map array of objects `[{ingredient: '', quantity: ''}]` and get properties from it with destructuring and this is the code

```
 <ul>
     {this.state.ingredients.map(({ ingredient, quantity }, k) => {
        return (
          <div key={k}>
            <li key={k}>{ingredient} - {quantity}</li><br />
          </div>
        )
     })}
 </ul>
```

ingredient and quantity returns undefined even thought they have values in state, but there is also something, there is as many `<li>` in `<ul>` as lenght of array of objects. so how is this possible? is there any way to fix it?

Here is console logging:

[image]

and here is image of logging state.ingredients

[image]

and this is how i am getting ingredients from server

```
 axios.get(`/api/recipe/${params.id}/${params.name}`)
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then(data=>{

        var jdata = JSON.parse(data.recipe)
        this.setState({
           ingredients: jdata.ingredients,
           ... other properties

        })
        console.log(jdata.ingredients)
    })
```

Comment: Looks good, make sure you have `ingredients` really has `objects` containing the required `keys`

Comment: just before return (), try to console.log(this.state.ingredients), what s the result? Plus you have a outer node which has a key and inner li element doesn t need a key.

Comment: @FurkanO I did it, it loggeed empty array first time and then it logged two more times valid arrays. regardless there were only two object in array

Comment: try this: `this.state.ingredients.map((item, key) => ( <span>{item}</span> ))`
remove additional {}

Comment: @FurkanO i did exactly that

Comment: @FurkanO, First time nothing, other two times, undefined & undefined

Comment: @Alex i did `item.ingredient` instead and it did not work neither

Comment: what do you mean by keys are different

Comment: Can you add more code to show as to how the state is initialised?

Comment: in other page I send array of objects to server and in this page i query that array from db

Comment: There is no hint of how the state gets its data from your current code sample. So unless you edit your question with code related to how state gets its data, none of us can help you.

Comment: Do you need more info?\

Comment: Just before `this.setState({  ingredients: jdata.ingredients` can you please console.log(jdata.ingredients) and tell me what the result is?

Comment: (2) [Array(1), Array(1)]
0: Array(1)
0: {ingredient: "sdasd", quantity: "asdas"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
1: Array(1)
0: {ingredient: "asdasd", quantity: "dsd"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output `console.log(JSON.stringify(jdata.ingredients))`, your array is array of arrays, covert your array of arrays to a single array.

```
this.setState({
  ...
  ingredients: [].concat.apply([], jdata.ingredients),
  ...
})
```

```js
const arrays = [[{"ingredient":"sdasd","quantity":"asdas"}],[{"ingredient":"asdasd","quantity":"dsd"}]]

const merged = [].concat.apply([], arrays);

console.log(merged)
```

Comment: if that's the data, then why are getting `undefined` when you log inside map?

Comment: I do not know really this is confusing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194901/discussion-between-junius-l-and-ilia).

Comment: [flatten array](https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/flattening-multidimensional-arrays-in-javascript/)